# How to run a python program from python 3.8.0 IDLE shell

Tags: python

I want to launch the program Tip_and_Tax_Calculator.py from a folder named Python27 in a python 3.8.0 IDLE shell but I want to know which code will work. I have tried the exec function and execFile but they do not work, I don't know if I am using them in the wrong way too.

```
import Tip_and_Tax_Calculator
exec('C:\Python27\Tip_and_Tax_Calculator.py')
```

The error I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/Jayan
>   Subramanian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Project
>   Launcher.py", line 1, in  import Tip_and_Tax_Calculator
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tip_and_Tax_Calculator

Comment: what means "do not work" ? Do you get error message or what? Always put full error message in question because we can't read in your mind. I see only one problem - in folder `Python27 can be code in Python 2.7 which is little different and it may not work with any Python3.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `exec` function combined with `open` and `read` in the following way for `python 3.x`:

Notice I change from **\** to **/**:

```
exec(open('C:/Python27/Tip_and_Tax_Calculator.py').read())
```

The method you tried and specified is relevant for `python 2.x`.

Another issue, you do not need to import the `Tip_and_Tax_Calculator`

**EDIT**

after the user added the error message the problem that the script didn't  run is the fact the module `Tip_and_Tax_Calculator` is not in the current shell directory, so one need to specify its full/relative path

Comment: if it has the read function, would it actually launch the program or just show me the code, sorry for not putting the message, i am a beginner in python and stack overflow

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jayan Subramanian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Project Launcher.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Tip_and_Tax_Calculator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tip_and_Tax_Calculator'`

Comment: This error says that it not "know" what is `Tip_and_Tax_Calculator` module, you need to specify it by path if its not in the shell current directory